# Sending lists of variables to python via AJAX through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

In my project I have javascript iterating through a set of radio buttons. First it checks to see if the selected button in the nameset has been changed, then if it has been, it records the value of the newly selected button for that row, appending it to a variable `dataString`, before moving on to the next buttonset. This is all well and good, it collects all the data perfectly. I run into issues when I try to send that data through AJAX, however.

For each row that is changed, I append a `rowName` variable and a `deviceName` variable do `dataString`. Ideally I want to send these such that when I get the data to Python, I end up with a `rowName` list and a `deviceName` list, as happens when you send multiple variables of the same name.

My AJAX call is as follows:

```
var call= $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/savestate.py",
    data: dataString
}).done(function() {
    document.getElementById("upper").innerHTML+=(call.responseText);
});
```

As I said, the data I need to send gets collected well enough. Right now, `dataString` is formatted so that it looks like this:

```
"{rowName: 'firstRowName', deviceName: 'firstDeviceName', rowName: 'secondRowName', deviceName: 'secondDeviceName'}"
```

I have also tried changing the AJAX call so that the `data:` call looks like:

```
data: {dataString}
```

And formatted `dataString` to look like:

```
"rowName: 'firstRowName', deviceName: 'firstDeviceName', rowName: 'secondRowName', deviceName: 'secondDeviceName'"
```

Either way I try to send it, the data does not get to the python script. When I return the data from Python, it comes out as

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```

Now since the format of the `data:` attribute in the AJAX call is `{keyname: value, etc}`, is it possible to send the data in a premade list in that format, or do I have to change the way I've formatted `dataString` and send it some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up achieving the desired effect two ways.

**First Method:** Thinking back to how I performed AJAX requests prior to implementing JQuery, I formatted `dataString` to

```
rowName=firstRowName&deviceName=firstDeviceName&rowName=secondRowName&deviceName=secondDeviceName
```

and so on. Then I simply appended that to my url in the AJAX call, so that it looked like:

```
url:"http://localhost/cgi-bin/saveState.py"+dataString
```

**Second Method:** The other way that I got it to work was to format the `dataString` the same way as in the First Method, but then simply use that as my `data` attribute.

```
data: dataString
```

I found it strange that this worked, since it doesn't at all follow the usual format for the `data:` call. But alas, it did indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

In your initial attempt, you are sending POST data to your Ajax method in JSON format. However, FieldStorage is expecting it in form format (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). The two methods you mention in your answer give it to the Ajax method in form format.

Besides your solutions, another approach is to use a JSON parsing library instead of FieldStorage. Exactly how you do this depends on the framework you are using - is it Django, Pyramid, etc?

Comment: So if I were to say `data: {foo: 'lorem', bar: 'ipsum'}` which is the format I kept seeing, it would take that as a form, but using `data: dataString` where `dataString={foo:'lorem', bar:'ipsum'}` would take it as a JSON?

Or to word it more clearly, why do I keep seeing examples with JSON formatted `data:` attributes if I need to use form formatted data to access it in the script?